# Is there a difference between SimCity 4 Deluxe and SC4 with Rush Hour?

Tags: simcity-4

[The online consensus seems to be No](http://www.google.com/search?q=differences+between+simcity+4+deluxe+and+rush+hour), but I'm not so sure.

While the manual for my boxed copy of Rush Hour is just a Deluxe manual with a different cover, page 10 of [said manual](http://www.futurecity.org/sites/default/files/sc4rh_deluxe_handbook_0.pdf) shows a well-developed region named "Puget Sound," which does look like the Seattle area. But there is no such region in my installation of Rush Hour on top of plain SC4. Maybe Deluxe comes with this and other regions not in Rush Hour.

Comment: On disc 1 I have the following regions: - Berlin - Fairview - London - New York - San Francisco - Timbuktu On disc 2 I have no region directories.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference I have both the Deluxe and the SC4 w/ Rush Hour. They both have same regions and the like. I think if I remember correctly the only difference was one had the patches installed and the other didn't.